# Flex 4: Part of the content in a Scroller not showing up

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, scroller

in my project I have a Panel which is using a custom skin that I created based on the Spark Panel Skin. In this skin I added a Spark Scroller to the display Group (the "contentGroup"), to this group I add "ListItems" that have some Labels and Images.

Everything was working fine untill today when I noticed that when the vertical scroller reaches the bottom, there's still content to be shown as can be seen in the image:

(Since I can't post images, here's the link: http://s10.postimage.org/uwfqfqp15/Panel.jpg)

As you can see in the image the Scroller vertical scrollbar has reached the end but there is still something to below the bottom limit (as you can see my simple custom scrollbar hasn't reached the bottom).

Here's part of the panel skin code (the scroller part):

**PanelSkin.mxml:**

```
<s:Group id="algoGroup" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
    <s:Scroller id="contentScroller" x="0" y="0" width="85%" height="100%" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
        <s:Group id="contentGroup" x="0" y="0" width="85%" height="100%" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
    <componentes:customScroller id="contentScrollbar" x="10" y="10" width="10%" height="100%"/>
</s:Group>
```

**ListaItem.mxml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
     contentBackgroundAlpha="0.0"
     currentState="Horizontal"
     width.Horizontal="200" height.Horizontal="100"
     height.Vertical="260" width.Vertical="128">
<s:states>
    <s:State name="Horizontal"/>
    <s:State name="Vertical"/>
</s:states>
<fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import objectos.GlobalVars;

        /*Vars - State -> Vertical
        Bindable Vars -- Omitted
        */

        public var ID:Number = -1;

        public function resize(nW:Number, nH:Number):void
        {
            if(this.currentState == "Vertical")
            {
                _realIW = _iW2 = (_iW2 * nW) / _w2;
                _realIH = _iH2 = (_iH2 * nH) / _h2;

                if(_iW2 > _iH2)
                    _iW2 = _iH2;
                else
                    _iH2 = _iW2;

                _xImg = (_xImg * nW) / _w2;
                _yImg = (_yImg * nH) / _h2;

                _xTit = (_xTit * nW) / _w2;
                _yTit = (_yTit * nH) / _h2;
                Titulo.width = (Titulo.width * nW) / _w2;

                Titulo.setStyle("fontSize", (GlobalVars.instance.getGlobal("fontSize") * 0.9));

                _xDes = (_xDes * nW) / _w2;

                if(Titulo.measureText(Titulo.text).width > Titulo.width)
                    _yDes = (_yDes * nH) / _h2;
                else
                    _yDes = Titulo.y + Titulo.measureText(Titulo.text).height;

                Descricao.width = (Descricao.width * nW) / _w2;

                Descricao.setStyle("fontSize", (GlobalVars.instance.getGlobal("fontSize") * 0.7));

                _xPre = (_xPre * nW) / _w2;
                _yPre = (_yPre * nH) / _h2;
                Preco.width = (Preco.width * nW) / _w2;

                _xIco = (_xIco * nW) / _w2;
                _yIco = (_yIco * nH) / _h2;
                IconEspecial.width = (IconEspecial.width * nW) / _w2;
                IconEspecial.height = (IconEspecial.height * nH) / _h2;

                _xDeL = (_xDeL * nW) / _w2;
                _yDeL = (_yDeL * nH) / _h2;
                DescricaoL.width = (DescricaoL.width * nW) / _w2;

                DescricaoL.setStyle("fontSize", (GlobalVars.instance.getGlobal("fontSize") * 0.7));
            }
            else
            {
                _realIW = _iW = (_iW * nW) / _w;
                _realIH = _iH = (_iH * nH) / _h;

                if(_iW > _iH)
                    _iW = _iH;
                else
                    _iH = _iW;

                Imagem.x = (Imagem.x * nW) / _w;
                Imagem.y = (Imagem.y * nH) / _h;

                Titulo.x = (Titulo.x * nW) / _w;
                Titulo.y = (Titulo.y * nH) / _h;
                Titulo.width = (Titulo.width * nW) / _w;

                Titulo.setStyle("fontSize", (GlobalVars.instance.getGlobal("fontSize") * 0.9));

                Descricao.x = (Descricao.x * nW) / _w;
                Descricao.y = (Descricao.y * nH) / _h;
                Descricao.width = (Descricao.width * nW) / _w;

                Descricao.setStyle("fontSize", (GlobalVars.instance.getGlobal("fontSize") * 0.7));

                Preco.x = (Preco.x * nW) / _w;
                Preco.y = (Preco.y * nH) / _h;
                Preco.width = (Preco.width * nW) / _w;

                IconEspecial.x = (IconEspecial.x * nW) / _w;
                IconEspecial.y = (IconEspecial.y * nH) / _h;
                IconEspecial.width = (IconEspecial.width * nW) / _w;
                IconEspecial.height = (IconEspecial.height * nH) / _h;

                _sW = (_sW * nW) / _w;
                _sY = (_sY * nH) / _h;
            }
        }

        private function resizeImg():void
        {
            var ratio:Number = Imagem.contentWidth / Imagem.contentHeight;

            if(Imagem.contentWidth > Imagem.contentHeight)
            {
                if(this.currentState == "Vertical")
                {
                    Imagem.width = _iW2;
                    Imagem.height = _iW2 / ratio;   
                }
                else
                {
                    Imagem.width = _iW;
                    Imagem.height = _iW / ratio;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(Imagem.contentHeight > Imagem.contentWidth)
                {
                    if(this.currentState == "Vertical")
                    {
                        Imagem.height = _iH2;
                        Imagem.width = _iH2 * ratio;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Imagem.height = _iH;
                        Imagem.width = _iH * ratio;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(this.currentState == "Vertical")
                    {
                        Imagem.height = (_iH2 > _iW2)?_iW2:_iH2;
                        Imagem.width = ((_iH2 > _iW2)?_iW2:_iH2) * ratio;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Imagem.height = (_iH > _iW)?_iW:_iH;
                        Imagem.width = ((_iH > _iW)?_iW:_iH) * ratio;
                    }
                }
            }

            Imagem.x += (_realIW - Imagem.width) / 2;
            Imagem.y += (_realIH - Imagem.height) / 2;
        }

        public function get useBar():Boolean
        {
            if(Separador != null)
                return Separador.visible;
            else
                return false;
        }
        public function set useBar(value:Boolean):void
        {
            if(Separador != null)
                Separador.visible = value;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:Image id="Imagem" x.Horizontal="10" y.Horizontal="10" x.Vertical="{_xImg}" y.Vertical="{_yImg}" maintainAspectRatio="false" complete.Horizontal="resizeImg()" complete.Vertical="resizeImg()"/>
<s:Label id="Titulo" x="98" y="10" text="Label" width="102" maxDisplayedLines="2" x.Vertical="{_xTit}" y.Vertical="{_yTit}" verticalAlign.Vertical="middle" textAlign.Vertical="left"/>
<s:Label id="Descricao" x="98" y="43" text="Label" width="102" maxDisplayedLines="3" color="#999999" x.Vertical="{_xDes}" y.Vertical="{_yDes}"/>
<s:Label id="Preco" x="113" y="78" text="Label" width="87" maxDisplayedLines="1" x.Vertical="{_xPre}" y.Vertical="{_yPre}"/>
<mx:Image x="93" y="73" width="20" height="20" id="IconEspecial" x.Vertical="{_xIco}" y.Vertical="{_yIco}"/>
<mx:HRule id="Separador" x="0" y="{_sY}" width="{_sW}" strokeColor="#000000" shadowColor="#000000" includeIn="Horizontal"/>
<s:Label id="DescricaoL" x.Horizontal="1" y.Horizontal="177" x.Vertical="{_xDeL}" y.Vertical="{_yDeL}" text="Label" width="127" color="#999999" visible.Horizontal="false" maxDisplayedLines="3"/>
</s:Group>
```

Here's the code used to add the components dynamically (edited to include relevante parts only):

```
        var item:ListaItem = new ListaItem();

        var iW:Number = 0;
        var iH:Number = 0;

        if(yPos == -1 || xPos == -1)
        {
            yPos = 0 - ((_group.height - (10 * (_maxProdutosVisiveis - 1))) / _maxProdutosVisiveis) - 10;
            xPos = 0;
        }

        yPos += ((_group.height - (10 * (_maxProdutosVisiveis - 1))) / _maxProdutosVisiveis) + 10;
        xPos = 0;
        iW = _group.width;
        iH = ((_group.height - (10 * (_maxProdutosVisiveis - 1))) / _maxProdutosVisiveis);

        item.x = xPos;
        item.y = yPos;

        item.ID = obj.idProduto;
        item.Titulo.text = (obj.Titulo_Produto != null)?obj.Titulo_Produto:obj.Titulo;
        item.Descricao.text = obj.Descricao;
        item.Preco.text = obj.Valor + " €";

        item.IconEspecial.source = this.specialIcon;

        _margem = iH + 10; 

        item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToApresentacao);

        _group.addElement(item);
        _components.addItem(item);

        item.width = iW;
        item.height = iH;

        item.Imagem.source = obj.url;
```

`_maxProdutosVisiveis` is the maximum visible products at the same time
`obj` is the object holding the data for the ListItem

I think that I have included everything relevant, but feel free to ask for anything else.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I didn't read all you code, but it seems far too complicated for what it's actually doing. It's almost certainly unnecessary to lay out each item by setting it's x,y,width,height. Most of the time it's far easier to just use a <VerticalLayout> and let Flex do the layout for you, then there won't be any little errors in there that would mess things up.

Comment: I would use that but this is only part of the code, the component is build so that it's contents can be display in any way you like, for instance with the right properties set it'll display the list items in a "W".

SOLVED: In the ListaItem, I forgot to add the default width and height in the root component.

Comment: If you solved your answer, please do not change your subject line to say "solved" and edit the question to include the answer.  Post your answer as a formal answer; and then select it as such.

Comment: At the time it didn't allowed me to do that, I knew that I would forget to come back and post the answer so I edited the question.
Corrected it according to the recomendation, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of search and trying different approaches to the problem I noticed that I forgot to add the default height and width for the ListaItem.

Changing:

**ListaItem.mxml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    contentBackgroundAlpha="0.0"
    currentState="Horizontal"
    width.Horizontal="200" height.Horizontal="100"
    height.Vertical="260" width.Vertical="128">
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    contentBackgroundAlpha="0.0"
    currentState="Horizontal"
    width="200" height="100"
    height.Vertical="260" width.Vertical="128">
```

Makes everything work again. Thank you everyone anyway :)